# any tool to automate REST api s and piping

Tags: rest

i want to know is there any tool/product/library to call rest api and process its output, add some conditional logic to further call another rest api call. Something similar to yahoo pipes.
The tool should have a UI to configure all these instead of writing a program.

Comment: Voting to close as offsite resource recommendation requests are offtopic.

Comment: may i know why it is down voted?

Comment: Off topic but you might look at SnapLogic

Comment: @jayanth Probably for the reason I just noted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Postman.
Link: https://www.getpostman.com/